# Why does STM32 use a two-stage initialization process? What is the primary purpose of each stage?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I'm learning to use STM32 microcontrollers using CubeMX to generate a project. I've noticed that CubeMX generates two basic stages of initialization for nearly every peripheral:

(A) Within the `stm32fxxxx_hap_msp.c` file, it defines a number of callbacks of the form `HAL_XXX_MspInit()`.

(B) Within `main.c`, it defines a number of functions of the form `MX_XXX_Init()`.

Sometimes a given peripheral's `HAL_XYZ_Init()` function is called from within (A) as it is with the ADC and RTC. Other times a given peripheral's `HAL_XYZ_Init()` function is called from within (B) as it is done with GPIO.

Both sets of functions call `__HAL_RCC_xxxx` macros extensively.

I can't make heads or tails of the usage pattern and neither the HAL guide nor reference manual give much direction here.

So, questions:

1. I suspect that the callback format provided by (A) has something to do with the uC waking from low-power modes, but I am not positive about this. Is this correct, or what is the purpose of the `HAL_XXX_MspInit` callback format?
2. I noticed that (A) contains more user-definition block comments indicating room for my code to cohabit the functions generated by CubeMX. But why, for instance, would it be wrong to move code from (B) into the space of (A) in order to keep my initialization sequence clear and easy to read?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to answer my own question.

The `HAL_XXX_MspInit()` functions are called by their respective `HAL_XXX_Init()` functions. As an example, when `main()` calls its `MX_I2C_Init()`, this prepares a global structure (defined in main.c) for initializing the I2C peripheral.

The call stack goes (roughly, with omissions):

`main()`         [written by CubeMX]
`MX_I2C_Init()`  [written by CubeMX]
`HAL_I2C_Init()` [provided by HAL Drivers and put in `Drivers/` by CubeMX]
`HAL_I2C_MspInit()` [empty version provided by HAL Drivers, overrided by CubeMX in `Core/Src/stm32fxxx_hal_msp.c` ]

Note that this means that you can call the `_MspInit()` and `_MspDeinit()` functions during your code's runtime. You may choose to do this, for example, to change low-level resource state before or after a change in power modes.

This answer (and other details concerning HAL call flow) is only hinted at by the **Description of HAL and LL Drivers** document, and is best confirmed by checking the HAL source code. This code is quite a bit more friendly than you might expect, and is located under your project tree under HAL_Drivers for any CubeMX project.

Comment: The code in `system_stm32fxxxx.c` is typically called before `int main(void)` and any linker injected loading code. It can be required to have the clock tree and external memory accessible before calling `main()` or to speed up the linker-loading.

Comment: There is even more initialisation code. Look at the startup directory and the `.s` file.